# AES/CBC Encryption: added padding but still getting IV error

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm very new to encryption and I've been tasked to encrypt a password before verifying to the server (I know it's bad practice but I'll have to follow.). This is my encryption method:

```
public static String encrypt(String src) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        Key key = makeKey();
        AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = makeIv();

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        return Base64.encodeBytes(cipher.doFinal(src.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

 static AlgorithmParameterSpec makeIv() {
        return new IvParameterSpec(ENCRYPTION_IV.getBytes(encoding));
}


static Key makeKey() {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] key = md.digest(ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes(encoding));
        return new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where the iv is composed of a 13 character string. I specified the padding but why do I still get the `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be 16 bytes long.` error? How do I really implement this encryption method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding only applies to the data being encrypted. The data will almost always be a little longer/shorter than the encryption blocks you are encrypting it into, so that last block will require some padding.

However your IV needs to be 16 bytes, padding your IV with zero's would be a security hole otherwise.

Comment: How do i pad my iv with zero's? I know that I'm not following the standard way of encryption but i am implementing an iOs code to android so I dont really have a choice

Comment: You don't want to pad it, that would be bad. Ensure you are generating a full 16-byte one.